# Passing keystore password to Cordova Android through the command line

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova project which I am trying to build for Android. I am using Cordova 5.3.3 and cordova-android 5.0.0. According to the documentation of Cordova Android found [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/tools.html) in order for cordova to sign the release apk that it produces I need to pass to it the signing configuration, including the keystore password and key password. When I include this configuration in by build.json (which I pass to my cordova build command through the --buildConfig attribute) everything works as expected. Since however the build.json is committed to Git, and I would like for the keystore and key passwords to not be in there for everyone to read, I am trying to find another way to pass cordova these passwords. The documentation states that:

> These parameters can be specified using the command line arguments
>   above to build or run scripts.

which leads me to believe that I could run the following build command to pass the password in the command line instead of including it in the build.json:

```
cordova build android --release --buildConfig cordova-config/build.json --password myPassword
```

This however fails with the following error:

> Unknown platforms: myPassword

Am I misreading something in the documentation or is this an issue with the version of cordova-android that I'm using?

Comment: Which IDE you are using? Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: The IDE doesn't really matter. What I'm trying to do is execute the cordova build command from the command line.

Comment: put the build.json on the gitignore so it isn't published

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the command:

```
 cordova build android --release --keystore=pathToKeystore --storePassword=kspassword --alias=aliasName --password=aliasPassword
```

But there is a bug and it doesn't work

If you update the project to cordova android 5.1.0 and replace the platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js with [this code](https://github.com/Icenium/cordova-android/blob/kerezov/fix-parse-options/bin/templates/cordova/lib/build.js) it will work (It might work with cordova android 5.0.0, but didn't test)

Another options are not to commit the build.json, or don't set the passwords, if you don't provide passwords on the build.json you will be promted to enter them manually

Comment: I also expected this to work, but instead I get the following error:
Unknown platforms: yourKeystore.keystore, yourKeystorePassworkd, yourAlias, yourAliasPasswork

Comment: I've updated the command and the answer, there is a bug and --keystore param doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed, using an equals sign seems to solve the problem. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Without changing the build.js code? Then the bug I told you might affect only to cordova android 5.1.0

Comment: Yes, it could affect only 5.1.0, truth is I didn't have time to check. In any case in 5.0.0 signing worked as soon as I used = instead of spaces for the command line properties.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a double dash, should be:

```
 cordova build android --release --buildConfig cordova-config/build.json -- --password myPassword
```

See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#signing-an-app

> Note: You should use double -- to indicate that these are
>   platform-specific arguments, for example: